# Task Manager shows wrong process memory usage

Tags: windows, memory, process, task-manager, process-explorer

I don't have much info on this one, other than it happened some time ago (can't pinpoint what could've caused it) and a reboot doesn't fix it.

Here are a couple of screenshots:

[image: short process list in process explorer, firefox.exe has 678K working set usage]

[image: short process list in task manager, firefox.exe has 430K private working set usage]

I'm completely clueless and so are the friends I asked. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen if you have customised your regional settings and the decimal symbol and digit grouping symbol are the same.

Go to Control Panel → Clock, Language and Region → "Change date, time or number formats", click on "Additional settings..." and make sure the two symbols are different.

Comment: This did solve my problem and I hadn't found the first time it was answered because I was looking for different keywords. Thank you for the solution and I apologize for the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Working set and Private Working set are different metrics, they will not be the same.

Working set includes non private memory such as shared dlls, and will be higher for a Win32 application that uses 3rd party libraries, including ones supplied by the operating system. Private working set memory is not shared with any other applications.

Comment: I think he's referring to the fact that the figures in the memory usage columns are several orders of magnitude too small.

Comment: well that is quite an interesting issue